# ModuleNotFoundError on Librosa even after following all the steps on the internet

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, librosa, anaconda3

[Error showing up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrPxi.png)

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-55d8c0d02ff9> in <module>
      3 import os
      4 import pandas as pd
----> 5 import librosa
      6 import glob
      7 import librosa.display

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'librosa'
```

I tried `pip install librosa` and `conda install -c conda-forge librosa`.
I tried installing it in the `C:\Program Files\Python39` directory. I tired all of the steps to do on the internet but nothing worked.
What should I do? Please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please check what is the python version that you're using for installing librosa and what python version you're using to run the program.

One better way is to check from the python interpreter.

As a rule of thumb, best way to manipulate packages is by creating a virtualenv and segregating the project dependencies.

To create a virtual environment and link it to Jupyter notebook , below steps would be helpful

1. create a virtualenv

   ```
   virtualenv venv
   ```
2. activate virtualenv and install ipykernel

   ```
   source venv/bin/activate
   pip install --user ipykernel
   ```
3. add virtualenv to Jupyter notebook

   ```
   python -m ipykernel install --user --name=venv
   Installed kernelspec venv in /home/user/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/venv
   ```
4. Now you can `Jupyter notebook` and virtualenv will be linked in the notebook. you can install modules in the virtualenv and can use it in the notebook.

more details [here](https://www.slideshare.net/dhineshsunderganapathi/intro-tovenvpy3)

Comment: I am currently using Python 3.9

Comment: Can you use virtual environment and try installing the package and then import  it in the code

Comment: I did make a virtual env and tried installing again but it didn't work

Comment: Could you please share the screenshots of the error you're facing and possibly the commands you're using

Comment: Yep, I updated the question with the picture

Comment: In  Jupyter notebook, you need to specify the virtual environment, follow this https://www.slideshare.net/dhineshsunderganapathi/intro-tovenvpy3

Comment: Glad to hear it worked, do upvote the answer if you find the answer is  legitimate